# How can I restrict the MySite owners to have limited permissions on their MySite

Tags: 2010, permissions, my-site

Is it possible to restrict the MySite owners (Site Collection administrator) to have limited permissions on their Mysites.

Please let me know about possible approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a previous discussing regarding this that I'd suggest you check out.

[Limit users permission in their own my site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21787/limit-users-permission-in-their-own-my-site)

Particularly, the solution provided by https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/35690/9345.

Hope it helps!